# Using rlist on a list of imported Excel sheets causes problems when filtering on certain names

Tags: r, filter, excel-import, error-list

I have dug into `rlist` and `purrr` and found them to be quite helpful in working with lists of pre-structured data. I tried to solve the problems arising on my one to improve my coding skills - so thanks to the community of helping out! However, I reached a dead-end now:

I want to write a code which is needed to be written in a way, that we throw our excel files in xlsm format to the folder an r does the rest.

I Import my data using:

```
vec.files<-list.files(pattern=".xlsm")
vec.numbers<- gsub("\\.xlsm","",vec.files)

list.alldata <- lapply(vec.files, read_excel, sheet="XYZ")
names(list.alldata) <- vec.numbers
```

The data we call is a combination of charaters, Dates (...).

When I try to use the `rlist-package` everything works fine until I try to use to filter on names, which were in the excel file not a fixed entry (e.g. Measurable 1), but a reference to another field (e.g. `=Table1!A1`, or an Reference).

If I try to call a false element I get this failure:

```
list.map(list.alldata, NameWhichWasAReferenceToAnotherFieldBefore)

Fehler in eval(.expr, .evalwith(.data), environment()) : 
  Objekt 'Namewhichwasareferencetoanotherfieldbefore' nicht gefunden
```

I am quite surprised, as if I call

```
names(list.alldata[[1]])
```

I get a vector with the correct entries / names.

As I identified the `read_excel()` as the problem causing reason I tried to add `col_names=True`, but did not help. Also `col_names=False` calls the correct arguments into the dataset.

I assume, that exporting the data as a .csv would help, but this is not an option. Can this be easily done by r in a pree-loop?

In my concept of working assessing the data by the names is essential and there is no work around so I really appreciate your help!

Comment: hi jan-philip, your question is a bit vague without at least showing us how your input-sheets are structured and a clue as to what you envision your results to look like. at first glance it just looks like you are not adressing the sublists correctly but without more info about your data structure this is just a guess

Comment: Hey DJ, thanks for, the imput dataset is usually  tibble [51 x 226] and will be growing towards more in y-direction [if i get this resolved here ...;)]

Comment: maybe you can dput() some small sample of the original data as well as show (in a picture or another dput()) how you want to do this. i have a hard time imagining the structure your data has.

Comment: Hey DJ, thanks for the response, the imput dataset is usually  tibble [51 x 226] and will be growing towards more in y-direction [if i get this resolved here ...;)] It contains character, number and logic columns. By doing a reduced file I [51x10] resolved the problem. So it works in general, meaning it is problem of the size of the Inputdata. Any idea of what I could do better / improve? What could cause such a problem in the InputData? [I will try to dput() some of the data later that day]